# Python Line Integral Convolution

Tags: python, scipy

I tried to use the scikits.vectorplot Tool for creating Line Integral Convolution results. It does not work and always and up with "no module named lic_integral". I compiled the module correctly.

So is there another solution for calculating LIC in Python?

I found this thread where somone used the module:
https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/14370/line-integral-convolution-lic-requirements

Thanks in advance

Comment: It sounds likely to be an installation issue. Can you show us more explicitly what you tried to do?

Answer (score 0):

@gaberchen. Unfortunately I just saw this question today.
I posted that question.
It turns out that, to use this packets, you should first run:

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

Then you can call:

```
python lic_demo
```

I didn't test the version that you mentioned, but it works for this one:

http://scipy.github.io/old-wiki/pages/Cookbook/LineIntegralConvolution